# How to combine references for two Ko ObservableArrays

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have two observable arrays representing the same data. The issue is that these are created async, in no particular order, and do not know about each other until one of them is already bound to the dom. In one direction, this works fine as the non-dom array can simply be set to the dom array. In the reverse order, however I'd have to rebind:

```
myDomArray = myOtherArray; //now I have to rebind the dom
```

In other words I want something like this:

```
ko.combine(myObservable1, myObservable2);
```

This would combine them such that behind the scenes in ko's internal event framework, they are now the same.

Thanks in advance!

***Disclaimer***: I'm willing to modify or reach deep into library code to pluck out functionality if need be, as this is most likely outside the scope of what was intended with this library.

Comment: I'm not following this question.  Can you post a simple jsfiddle using window.setTimeout to simulate the async nature to highlight the problem you're seeing and attempting to solve?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the need for 2 arrays for the same data?

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298816/how-to-create-a-computed-observable-array-in-knockout>?