# How to splice ko.computeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, drag-and-drop

I got these two ko.computeds lists that I want to drag and drop among, but also moved with pushbuttons to remove an add to lists.

However I cannot make them work with both the dragndrop and the pushbutton functionality.

For the drag and drop I use Ryan Niemeyers excellent sortable library.

I guess I need to make my computeds writable, but this is where I get stuck and can´t seem to get rid of the error "splice is not a function" for the computed.

Hence the sorting by drag and drops fails.

This is one of the computers:

```
         this.availableTexts = ko.computed({
            read: function(){
               return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.texts(), function(text) {
               return text.sceneID() === null;
            })
          },
          write: function(value){
            return value;
          },
          owner: this
        });
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/yLvrp7zz/

Answer (score 1):

Niemeyer's knockout-sortable library works with `splice` *internally* to sort an array of items ([source](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/blob/master/src/knockout-sortable.js#L290)). I believe it simply won't work on a computed, even if it returns an array and has a correct write method...

I'd suggest to use the `visible` binding to hide individual items. You'll have to expose `projectID` or map your items to include a computed like so:

```
var projectID = 1;
self.allScenes = ko.observableArray(scenes.map(function(scene) {
  return Object.assign({}, scene, {
    isVisible: ko.computed(function() { 
      return scene.projectID === projectID;
  });
});
```

Alternatively, in viewmodel:

```
self.projectId = 1;
```

in HTML:

```
<li data-bind="visible: projectID === $parent.projectId"> ... </li>
```

Comment: That´s a very good suggestion for a workaround, @user3297291. However I get back to the fact that the texts I am binding against "visible" statement still is a computed since it is filtered on projectID. I could of course add the projectID to the visible, but that would potentially load lots of text in my view. Surely there must be a way to work around this with subscribe-function?

Comment: You may use `if` binding on virtual element instead of `visible` (`<!-- ko if: projectId === ... --><li ...>...</li><!-- /ko -->`. And elements inside `if` will be excluded from DOM and processing in the right case.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16464935/4024558

You can use `observableArray.filter` instead of `computed` in your case.

Suddenly I can't fork your fiddle. So you can replace your js with this http://pastebin.com/jjNQ39nJ and it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Tarwirdur Turon! This is pretty close. However I rely on static variables for the projectID and/or sceneID. How would a filter with two inputs look, the second being the value (projectID/sceneID) checked against?  Important notice. The value of projectID/sceneID would have to be observables themselves as these are input into the selection.

Comment: @AsleG I see here error: `... if (!scene) {return [];} ...`. It is in ko.utils.arrayFilter predicate. This function must return boolean value. I suppose, you mean there `... if (!scene) {return false;} ...`. If you think that something else is working wrong - say what are you doing and what do you expect.

Comment: The predicate is a ko.utils.arrayFilter returning array elements isn´t it? I need the filter to return an empty array when scene is not defined, else I will have an error on the initialization of the view. 
This is a general problem for me. When a scene not is selected the view is failing.

Comment: @AsleG No. `predicate` is a function that used as second argument of arrayFilter. It calls on each element of array and must return `true` (include element from filtered array) or `false` (exclude element from filtered array). If you write `return [];` it will be assimilated to `true`. (check it with `if([]) {console.log("true");} else {console.log("false")};`);

Comment: Thanks, @Tarwirdur Turon!  But how do I get the filter function to return an empty array in case the matching condition is undefined?

Comment: @AsleG this function calls on **each** element. So if you write `if (!scene) return false;` it means `false` for all element. So result will be empty observable array. Check it on your fiddle.